# How integrated Mercurial with JIRA 6.1.7?

Tags: mercurial, jira

How to integrated JIRA with Mercurial:

1. Fisheye - not possible for this task
2. Mercurial plugin not worked o the JIRA 6.1.7

Answer (score 0):

FishEye supports Mercurial, so perhaps there is some other restriction?

File a support ticket about #2 since it is marked as supported. However, as the original author I recommend using FishEye instead of the plugin as a better solution architecturally